# What is the time complexity of this priorityQueue destructor?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, doubly-linked-list

I'm not sure if the time complexity is O(n) or O(n^2). Can someone please clarify? I want to say its O(n^2) because of the traversal in the destructor and the traversal in findMin().

findMin basically just traverses the doubly linked list and finds and returns the minimum value.

```
    ~priorityQueue()
    {
        for(temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        {
            extractMin();
        }
    }

    double extractMin()
    {
        if (head == NULL)
            //do nothing
        min = findMin(head);
        else if(min == head)
        {
            head = head->next;
            head ->prev = NULL;
            double output = min->data;
            delete min;
            return output;
        }
        else if (min == tail)
        {
            double output = min->data;
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
            delete min;
            return output;
        }
        else if(min == head && min == tail)
        {
            return min->data;
            tail = NULL;
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            double output = min->data;
            min->prev->next = min->next;
            min->next->prev = min->prev;
            delete min;
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Such questions probably belong on the codereview site, not SO. At a glance, it looks like O(N^2).  Why search for the min value? Just delete the thing from one end to the other. Also, you would do well to separate out the doubly linked list into a separate class. Far, far better would be to scrap the whole thing and use `std::priority_queue`.  Use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Comment: Regardless of where you post, you would need a [mcve]

Comment: Neither, because it's not reliable.  `temp` is likely to point at a deleted object some time it's used within the destructor.

Comment: Never heard of codereview. I'll definitely be checking it out. Thank you though!